# Setting a view controller's view's frame with constraints?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

This app has no storyboard. This is the root view controller where `ViewController2` (`page2`) is instantiated. `ViewController2`'s view is given constraints (leading, top, width, height). The constraints appear to work great except when I create a `UINavigationController` in `page2`.

```
class ViewController0: UIViewController {


    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    let page1 = ViewController1()
    let page2 = ViewController2()


    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.allButUpsideDown
    }


    override func loadView() {

        setView()
        addScrollView()
        addToScrollView()

    }


    func setView() {

        view = UIView()

    }


    func addScrollView() {

        scrollView.bounces = false
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
        scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
        scrollView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true

    }


    func addToScrollView() {

        addChildViewController(page1)
        page1.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.addSubview(page1.view)
        page1.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        page1.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        page1.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        page1.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
        page1.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
        page1.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        addChildViewController(page2)
        page2.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.addSubview(page2.view)
        page2.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        page2.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: page1.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        page2.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        page2.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
        page2.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
        page2.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        page2.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    }


}
```

Because for the navigation controller to work properly on `page2`, I must explicitly set the view's frame, as seen below with `view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds` *even though* I set it in `ViewController0` using constraints. If I don't *again* set the view's frame like so (below), the bounds of the view extend to infinity and the constraints within `page2` become useless.

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {


    var navigation = UINavigationController()
    let navigationRoot = ViewController3()


    override func loadView() {

        setView()
        addNavigation()

    }


    func setView() {

        view = UIView()
        view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds

    }


    func addNavigation() {

        self.addChildViewController(navigationRoot)
        navigationRoot.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: navigationRoot)
        view.addSubview(navigation.view)

    }


}
```

I was under the impression that when you use constraints, you can forego the frame property of views entirely. Did I not set up the constraints correctly? Or because this is purely programmatic I must, therefore, at times, explicitly set the frame of a view?

Comment: This tech note might help https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2154/_index.html

Comment: You don't have to set the frame if you have sufficient constraints. Keep it simple, logically top, bottom, leading and trailing constraints are sufficient for auto layout to determine the actual frame rect.

Comment: That's the problem, the constraints are sufficient, yet the view's frame needs to be set twice when that view becomes a navigation view controller--at least as I see it.

Comment: Thanks for the link @alparsons. I read through it and meet all of those requirements, which puzzles me further.